# Aurelia - no access to router in child router with viewports

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have an odd problem and do not seem to find the issue. I have a child router with two viewports and would like to access the router in one of the components (menu) loaded through the viewport. When I define the same routes with the viewports in the app.ts, the menu shows the route entries, but with the routes defined in the child router the router variable is undefined. I tried with a viewmodel for the menu and also with binding the router explicitly to the router-view tag, but no luck.

Would be great if someone could shed some light on this.

The reason for this is that I would like to create a different page layout with these viewports compared to an admin page. However I'm not sure if this separation is actually a good aproach. Maybe I could simply set the side viewport null for the admin page. But this would require some CSS rewriting I believe.

**app.ts**

```
config.map([
      {
        route: ['', 'child'],
        name: 'child',
        moduleId: 'child/child',
      },
      {
        route: 'admin',
        name: 'admin',
        moduleId: 'admin/admin,
      },
    ]);

this.router = router;
```

**child view**

```
<template> 
  [...]
  <router-view name="side"></router-view>

  <router-view name="main"></router-view>
</template>
```

**child vm**

```
export class Child{
  private router: Router

  private configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router){
    config.map([
      {
        route: 'myOrders',
        name: 'myOrders',
        nav: true,
        viewPorts: {
          main: { moduleId: 'components/some-vm/some-vm' },
          side: { moduleId: 'components/menu/menu.html' }
        }
      },
      {
        route: ['', 'allorders'],
        name: 'allorders',
        nav: true,
        viewPorts: {
          main: { moduleId: 'components/orders-table/orders-table' },
          side: { moduleId: 'components/menu/menu.html' }
        }
      }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

**menu view**

```
<template> 
  [...]
  ${router}  <!-- router is never accessible -->
  <ul class="nav">
    <li repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
      <a href.bind="row.href">${row.title}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: sounds like not an optimal approach. consider using compose.

Answer (score 1):

The binding context inside a `router-view` is not merged with the parent binding context. You might be able to do `$parent.router` (not tested this), but it's better to simply inject `Router` in the constructor of your menu view.

To clarify: every child router will get its own child container. Components which are loaded by that child router will have their dependencies resolved from that child container. Things like `Router` and `Element` are automatically registered to that child container, meaning you'll always get the "innermost" or "closest" instance relative to the component you're requesting it from.

So if you inject `Router` in your `App`, you'll get the root (`AppRouter`) and if you inject it in your menu view, you'll get the child router you need.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think that I already tried injecting the router but am not quite sure. I will give it a try when I find time. Thanks.

Comment: Main thing you need to be aware of is that the injected router will be the one that loaded the ViewModel you're injecting it in, whereas the router you get from `configureRouter()` will be a child of the injected router. They're not the same one. You might have tried injecting router in your root (App) and that would never work, because the App is the one that creates the root router.